# WPF/SL control to represent grapf on the map. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I need to create WPF/SL application to represent a graph on the map. The users will create and edit the graph vertices linked with geographic locations. 
Please recommend WPF/SL control suitable for this task.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great third party map controls, such as [Telerik's Map Control](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/map.aspx), which handle mapping, including adding your own geographic data.